# Command works in terminal but not as a shortcut command

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard-shortcuts, xdotools

My system: Debian 11 / Xfce

To quickly insert the same text in different e-mails, I tried to create a keyboard shortcut using a `xdotool type "text"` command At first I tested this command in a terminal and I got the text displayed on the terminal screen alright. Then I used it to create a keyboard shortcut: it didn't work anymore and I had to replace it by `sh -c 'xdotool type "text"'` .

Why do I have to use `sh -c` to create a keyboard shortcut that will insert text in an e-mail?

Comment: Please describe undesired outcome in a better way than just "it didn't work". What's also the issue of adding `sh -c` or anything alike?

Comment: to create this keyboard shortcut I first used **xdotool type "text"** as command but nothing happened and I had to add **sh -c '...'** . If I write a script that will be called as command I only use **xdotool type "text"** , no need of **sh -c** . Why this difference ?

Comment: "nothing happened", but where did you try to execute it?

Comment: I opened **Applications/settings/keyboard/Application Shortcuts** , then **+Add** then I wrote this command , without **sh -c**,  in the small window called **Command**

Comment: No, I mean where did you try to use the shortcut?

Comment: sorry , I misinterpreted your question . I first tried adding text to an empty file then I added text to an e-mail : with **sh -c** (or using the script) the shortcut works fine , without **sh -c** it doesn't work .

Comment: What if you use the absolute path to `xdotool` without `sh -c`?

Comment: I've already tried /usr/bin/xdotool , without sh -c it doesn't work either

Comment: I may have an explanation about why a script and **sh -c** are basically the same . If I want to run a script I can use **sh or bash script** ( I suppose I didn't use chmod u+x so the script is just a normal file ) , then a child process opens , because of **bash or sh** and runs **xdotool type "text"** . The same thing happens with **sh -** which starts a child process with **sh** and runs the command between '.....' which is **xdotool type "text"** . Does it make sense or is it rubbish ? Now , why do I need a child process ?

Comment: After some research on the net I finally mihgt have found why some commands cannot be interpreted by the built-in Xfce command interpreter : it's not a shell . So , to read the command and execute it one has to create a subshell , that's what the script or <sh -c> are doing , before this command can be run . Does that sound right ?